# ¿Cual seria la diferencia entre parámetros y argumentos de una función?

Tags: lenguaje-agnóstico

Sin tomar en consideración un lenguaje de programación especifico, Cual seria la diferencia entre parámetros y argumentos en cuanto a las funciones?

Ademas tomar en cuenta que según entendí del libro "código limpio", se recomienda que entre menos argumentos (si es posible ninguno) que se pasen a la función mas efectiva se vuelve porque?.

Si pueden agregar un **ejemplo** de ambos muchísimo mejor :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Un parámetro es una propiedad intrínseca de un procedimiento, dado que está incluido en su definición. Por ejemplo, un procedimiento que calcule la suma de dos números enteros necesitará dos parámetros, uno para cada número. En general, un procedimiento puede ser definido con cualquier número de parámetros (o ninguno). Si un procedimiento tiene parámetros, la parte de su definición que los especifica es llamada lista de parámetros.

En tanto, los argumentos son más bien los valores actuales asignados a los parámetros variables cuando la función es llamada.

Cuando se realiza una llamada a la función, los "valores" pasados se denominan argumentos.

En la práctica no se suele distinguir tajantemente entre ambos términos.

Te dejo la documentación oficial de [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/9kewt1b3.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

De forma adicional a lo que nuestro colega [sakulino](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/11132/sakulino) dice en su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/62008/4499), yo tambien quiero aportar algo, pues la principal diferencia entre parámetro y argumento es lo mismo que "identificador y valor" en pocas palabras.

Pero mi adición va a lo que preguntas es lo siguiente:

> Ademas tomar en cuenta que según entendí del libro "código limpio", se recomienda que entre menos argumentos (si es posible ninguno) que se pasen a la función mas efectiva se vuelve porque?.

---

**Pequeño edit:**
Bueno, la efectividad de una función depende de cómo esta fue creada y si cumple con su propósito.

---

Esto es, debido a que en la mayoría de sistemas operativos todo el código compilado realiza una acción, el código en sí no es interpretado por el ordenador *(¡De lo contrario serían humanos!)*, sino que lo unico que entiende el ordenador son una combinacion de `0` y `1` a lo largo del programa.

Sucede que al llamar a una función, a nivel de bits no se pasan argumentos, sino que todos esos bytes son cargados en registros, imaginemos el siguiente ejemplo:

```
mi_funcion(5, 3, "Hola");
```

El ordenador no sabe que está recibiendo, por lo que simplemente interpreta los argumentos de la función en reversa *(En algunos sistemas)*:

```
lea  eax, <direccion_del_string_'Hola'> ; Tercer argumento
mov  ebx, 3                             ; Segundo argumento
mov  ecx, 5                             ; Primer argumento.
call mi_funcion                         ; Llama a mi_funcion
```

<sup>*Esto no es ensamblador real*</sup>

Y en el cuerpo de la función, realiza las respectivas movidas para evitar el uso de direcciones de memoria.

La razón por la que una función sin parametros puede ser más eficiente que una con parametros, es porque el ordenador interpreta sólo una llamada, es decir, a mayor cantidad de parametros, mayor cantidad de asignaciones en registros, por ende un poco más lento *(O por lo menos eso entiendo yo)*

En una función sin argumentos simplemente haces:

```
mi_funcion:
    xor eax, eax
    nop
    ret

call mi_funcion
```

Y listo.

Answer (score 4):

La idea de utilizar pocos parámetros busca precisamente eso: código limpio, legible, fácil de entender, escribir, leer y darle mantenimiento. Si encuentras una función con por ejemplo, 16 parámetros, no es fácil leerla.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que tienes una función para registrar un cliente nuevo y la utilizas así:

```
IngresarNuevoCliente("Nombre1", "Nombre2", "Nombre3", "Apellido1", "Apellido2", "ApellidoCasada", fechaNacimiento, "Genero", "NumeroIdentificacionUnica", "Dirección", telefono)
```

Como ves, es una instrucción muy larga, tienes que recorrerla completamente para observar el contenido, y cuando la escribes, es fácil perder el orden de los parámetros (a mi me ha sucedido personalmente) y equivocarlos, y si son del mismo tipo no mostrará ningún error (por ejemplo, que cambies un apellido por un nombre) y será más dificil detectar el problema. Si estas debugueando también cuesta seguirle el orden a los parámetros. Y eso sin contar si a su vez, la función `IngresarNuevoCliente` pertenece a la lógica del negocio y llama a su vez otra función para almacenar esta información, que también tendrá N cantidad de parámetros.

Muy diferente es por ejemplo, utilizar una clase `Cliente`, crear un objeto `cliente` y asignarle valores conforme obtienes la información:

```
cliente.primerNombre = cajaTextoPrimerNombre.Text;
cliente.segundoNombre = cajaTextoSegundoNombre.Text;
.
.
.
cliente.telefono = cajaTextoTelefono.Text;
```

Y luego crear el cliente nuevo así:

```
IngresarNuevoCliente(cliente);
```

Es más clara su escritura y lectura, durante un debugueo puedes analizar el objeto y ahí estará disponible la información de manera mas legible.

¿Qué sucede si después necesitas capturar mas información del cliente? Simplemente modificas la clase y ya puedes capturar dicha información sin modificar tu función, que añadirle más parámetros a la función y volverla más complicada y susceptible de errores, así como a todas las funciones a las que esta haga llamada.

La idea de evitar por completo los parámetros me parece un poco exagerada, en general **estas son buenas prácticas, no leyes escritas en piedra**, y conforme se adquiere experiencia escribiendo código, sabrás cuales tomar en cuenta y por qué.